# Ansys fluent UDF file not being complied

Tags: user-defined-functions, fluent, ansys

I have tried to build my udf file after adding it. I ran as follows:

```
tbin\win64/DOF_Sol - Copy.c to libudf\src
udf_names.c and user_nt.udf files in 2ddp_host are upto date.
(system "copy "C:\PROGRA~1\ANSYSI~1\v181\fluent"\fluent18.1.0\src\udf\makefile_nt.udf "libudf\win64\2ddp_host\makefile" ")
        1 file(s) copied.
(chdir "libudf")(chdir "win64\2ddp_host")udf_names.c and user_nt.udf files in 2ddp_node are upto date.
(system "copy "C:\PROGRA~1\ANSYSI~1\v181\fluent"\fluent18.1.0\src\udf\makefile_nt.udf "libudf\win64\2ddp_node\makefile" ")
        1 file(s) copied.
(chdir "libudf")(chdir "win64\2ddp_node")
Done.
```

Later while compling it an error is popig up.

```
Inc\v181\fluent\ntbin\win64\libudf"...
Error at Node 0: The UDF library you are trying to load (libudf) is not compiled for parallel use on the current platform (win64).

The system cannot find the file specified.


Error at host: The UDF library you are trying to load (libudf) is not compiled for parallel use on the current platform (win64).

The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v181\fluent\ntbin\win64\libudf\win64\2ddp_host\libudf.dll

Error at Node 1: The UDF library you are trying to load (libudf) is not compiled for parallel use on the current platform (win64).

The system cannot find the file specified.


Error at Node 2: The UDF library you are trying to load (libudf) is not compiled for parallel use on the current platform (win64).

The system cannot find the file specified.


Error at Node 3: The UDF library you are trying to load (libudf) is not compiled for parallel use on the current platform (win64).

The system cannot find the file specified.


Error at Node 4: The UDF library you are trying to load (libudf) is not compiled for parallel use on the current platform (win64).

The system cannot find the file specified.


Error at Node 5: The UDF library you are trying to load (libudf) is not compiled for parallel use on the current platform (win64).

The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v181\fluent\ntbin\win64\libudf\win64\2ddp_node\libudf.dll
C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v181\fluent\ntbin\win64\libudf\win64\2ddp_node\libudf.dll
C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v181\fluent\ntbin\win64\libudf\win64\2ddp_node\libudf.dll
C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v181\fluent\ntbin\win64\libudf\win64\2ddp_node\libudf.dll
C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v181\fluent\ntbin\win64\libudf\win64\2ddp_node\libudf.dll
C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v181\fluent\ntbin\win64\libudf\win64\2ddp_node\libudf.dll
MPI Application rank 0 exited before MPI_Finalize() with status 2
 The fl process could not be started.
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U952B.jpg)

I have been running my fluent from vs prompt itself. I had set all the environment paths requied for the execution. The coding is working absolutly fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is common if you have chosen ansys parallel run.
It should be solved by selecting the serial version at the start of Fluent.
Other way is to have `PRF_GRSUMx(variable)` constructs in your UDF which take care for global summation.

Comment: Accepting the answer is much appreciated, if it solved your problem?